# Row product of matrix and column sum of matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix of size TxR and I am looking for a command to do the product of the rows (returning an 1 x R vector of the products). After that I want to sum over the columns, i.e. sum the R terms.

In Matlab this would be done something like this sum(prod(A,1),2), but I don't know the code for this in R.

I hope it make sense.

Thanks

Comment: It is decidedly unclear what you want. You state you want `the product of the rows` but then give `prod(A, 1)`, whereas the [Matlab help for `prod`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/prod.html) suggests what you wanted there is `prod(A, 2)`. Can you clarify if you want the products of each of the rows and then sum them?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
sum(apply(A, 1, prod))
```

apply the prod function across the rows (the 1 is the margin), sum the result.

Answer (score 8):

In base R:

```
mat <- matrix(c(1,2,3,
                4,5,6,
                7,8,9), byrow = TRUE, ncol = 3)

R <- apply(mat, 1, prod)
R
sum(R)

R> R
[1]   6 120 504
R> sum(R)
[1] 630
```

There is a nice alternative on CRAN called **matrixStats** which aims to add fast versions of other matrix functions to complement the `rowSums`, `colSums` (and their mean equivalents) in base R.

```
install.packages("matrixStats") ## install it from CRAN

## load matrixStats
library("matrixStats")
rowProds(mat)

R> rowProds(mat)
[1]   6 120 504
R> sum(rowProds(mat))
[1] 630
```

Answer (score 2):

Only a partial answer, but with rowSums it is possible to build your on base-R row-product-function:

```
mat <- matrix(c(1,1,0,
                1,3,-6,
                12,12,12), byrow = TRUE, ncol = 3)

# function based on rowSums
my_rowprod <- function(x) ifelse((rowSums(x < 0) %% 2) == 1, -1, 1) * exp(rowSums(log(abs(x))))

my_rowprod(mat)
#[1]    0  -18 1728
```

Comment: Interesting trick! I didn't even knew that a product was the exponential of the sum of the logarithm. I find a link on that from mathworld: [link](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Product.html)